# How to split one array in multiple arrays by adding an extra dimension in python xarray?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-xarray

I have the following `xarray`:

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

da = xr.DataArray(np.random.rand(25, 6),
                   [('time', pd.date_range('2000-01-01', periods=25)),
                    ('space', ['IA', 'IL', 'IN', 'VA', 'VL', 'VN'])])
```

Where `da.shape` yields `(25, 6)`.

I would like to split the `25` into `5`x`5` such that I get a 3D shape in the following form: `(5, 5, 6)`.

I honestly have no idea where to start. I looked up the docs and could not find any solution. I know I seek only a vectorized solution (i.e. no loops and `list.append()` stuff, because it will be too costly otherwise.

Can you help me with a solution to this problem?

**UPDATE:**

With `np.split(da, 5)` I managed to create a `list` of 5 `xarray`s inside with exactly the data I need. How do I make this step, but instead of converting to `list`, it stays an `xarray`, but it has one extra dimension?

Comment: "Vectorised" applies to operations on arrays. You might just want a "slice"

Comment: To be clear, I should emphasize that it's not a lopping solution which I am looking for. I can do it with loops and appends.

Comment: That wasn't what i suggested. Have you looked at "advamced indexing" for numpy?

Comment: I am looking at it now. My problem is with conversion from 2D to 3D. Meaning, I can efficiently view the data with `.sel` for example, but I cannot efficiently convert it to 3D.

Comment: Why are you trying to split the `time` dimension into two dimensions? What dimensions/coordinates are you looking to have in the resulting DataArray? I can think of reasons to do this, but to help we'd need something to put in place of your current time dim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was by using [`np.resize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.resize.html):

```
da_new = np.resize(da, (5,5,6))
```

Where (as expected) `da_new.shape` yields `(5, 5, 6)`. This works relatively quickly as well.